# Using Get-AzMetric to retrieve CPU utilization of specific set of Azure VM's

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I am using powershell to retrieve the avg cpu of specific azure vm's. The script is working but the data it is spitting out seems to be wrong.

```
$t=Get-Date
$st='2023-12-19T12:00:00Z'
$et='2023-12-21T12:00:00Z'

$cpu = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $vm.Id -TimeGrain 00:15:00 -StartTime $st -EndTime $et -
MetricName "Percentage CPU" -DetailedOutput

$cpu.data
```

Output:

TimeStamp : 12/21/2023 11:45:00 AM

Average   : 16.1115833333333

Minimum   :

Maximum   :

Total     :

Count     :

Actual:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why I am not getting the correct avg percentages?

Comment: Your script seems to be perfectly alright. Are you sure that you're taking time-zones into account when comparing the output from the script and the output from the metrics window in portal that you screenshotted?

Comment: @akseli I am not sure. How do you suggest I go by finding out if the timezones align?

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell to retrieve the avg cpu of specific azure vm's you need to modify the Time Granularity and Interval accordingly.

When executing this script in the Azure Cloud Shell, I got exact time output like below:

```bash
$cpu = Get-AZmetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/Identity-Resources/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<vmname>"-TimeGrain 00:01:00 -MetricName "Percentage CPU" -Detailedoutput
$CPU.data
```

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/DRGwdpf.png)]

In the Azure portal, make sure to adjust the Time Granularity and showtime as shown below.

[image]

Now when I check in portal its show correct time like below:

[image]

Comment: @CoCoBl Let me know if you have any queries?